# vb.net Reading an XML file with XmlReader

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have an XML file as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dice>
  <Type name="D3">
    <Sides>3</Sides>
  </Type>
  <Type name="D4">
    <Sides>4</Sides>
  </Type>
  <Type name="D6">
    <Sides>6</Sides>
  </Type>
  <Type name="D8">
    <Sides>8</Sides>
  </Type>
  <Type name="D10">
    <Sides>10</Sides>
  </Type>
  <Type name="D12">
    <Sides>12</Sides>
  </Type>
  <Type name="D20">
    <Sides>20</Sides>
  </Type>
  <Type name="D%">
    <Sides>100</Sides>
  </Type>
</Dice>
```

I would like to read the XML file and list the name attributes in a combobox but the below code does not insert the attribute names on form load for a window forms application.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Set the titles for the application
    Dim title As String = "Dice Bag"
    Me.Text = title

    'Loads the XML file
    Dim xmlDiceBag As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("dicebag.xml")
    Do While xmlDiceBag.Read()
        If xmlDiceBag.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso xmlDiceBag.Name = "type" Then
            cbDiceType.Items.Add(xmlDiceBag.GetAttribute(0))
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any an all help is appreciated...

Comment: I guess it is `xmlDiceBag.Name = "Type"` (See markup it is `Type` not a `type`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was the fact that the project and the XML file were named the same and the application did not which dicebag.xml to read from. changed the name of the xml file to dice.xml and it work perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this ->( `xmlDiceBag.Name = "type" ) should be this -> ( xmlDiceBag.Name = "Type"` )

Check **T** should be capital.

Comment: Changed the "Type" in the code to "type" and GetAttribute(0) to GetAttribute("name") still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Check for the case sensitivity: Should be this.

```
xmlDiceBag.Name = "Type"
```

Get the value of an attribute:

```
cbDiceType.Items.Add(xmlDiceBag.GetAttribute("name"))
```

Comment: Changed the "Type" in the code to "type" and GetAttribute(0) to GetAttribute("name") still does not work